Error pushing slow log display on the Kibana
Hi everyone I got any incident. Any day recently I got an error "Error pushing slow log display on Kibana". and show information in the following the image

Although the log on the agent server is still complete, why is it that when it is pushed to elastic search and kibana displays, it still does not push the complete log over time..
Everyone, please help me solve this problem thank you so much
